# WebListener prevents the web application to launch

Tags: java, vaadin, weblistener

I have a Vaadin web application, that is deploying OK.
BUT when I add a FolderWatcher service as a Listener using

```
@WebListener
```

The application fails to deploy, but it starts the thread if I disable the annotation `@WebListener` the application does deploy.

Folder watcher class

```
public class FolderWatchService {

private final WatchService watcher;
private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger( FolderWatchService.class.getName() );

/**
 * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
 */
public FolderWatchService(Path dir) throws IOException {
    this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
    this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey, Path>();

    walkAndRegisterDirectories(dir);
}

/**
 * Register the given directory with the WatchService; This function will be called by FileVisitor
 */
private void registerDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException 
{
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
    keys.put(key, dir);
}

/**
 * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the WatchService.
 */
private void walkAndRegisterDirectories(final Path start) throws IOException {
    // register directory and sub-directories
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            registerDirectory(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
 */
public void processEvents() {
    for (;;) {

        // wait for key to be signaled
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }

        Path dir = keys.get(key);
        if (dir == null) {
            LOGGER.log( Level.FINE, "WatchKey not recognized!!", "" );

            System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!");
            continue;
        }

        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

            // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Path name = ((WatchEvent<Path>)event).context();
            Path child = dir.resolve(name);


            String fileContent;



            // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then register it and its sub-directories
            if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                System.out.println("File created");
                LOGGER.log( Level.FINER, "New File created", "" );
                readFile(child.toString());
            }
        }

        // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            keys.remove(key);

            // all directories are inaccessible
            if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static void readFile(String pathname){

    try {
        File file = new File(pathname);

        StringBuilder fileContents = new StringBuilder((int)file.length());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        try {
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                fileContents.append(scanner.nextLine() + lineSeparator);
            }
            String fileContent = fileContents.toString();
            System.out.println("File name: "+FilenameUtils.getBaseName(pathname));
            LOGGER.log( Level.FINER, "File name: "+FilenameUtils.getBaseName(pathname), "" );
            String title = "File Title: "+fileContent.substring(0, 64).trim().lastIndexOf(System.getProperty("line.separator"))+"...";

        } finally {
            scanner.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

ContextLister class

```
@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("#### Folder watcher service destroyed");

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("#### Folder watcher service initialized");
         Path dir = Paths.get(PropertiesCache.getInstance().getProperty("file_input_location"));
            try {
                new FolderWatchService(dir).processEvents();
                System.out.println("#### Folder watcher service started");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("#### Folder watcher Problem");
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    }
```

EDIT: Added what is printed out by logs

```
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener 
lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 
1.5.2.
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener 
lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters 
[false], random [true].
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener 
lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener 
initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool 
getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool 
getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1392 ms
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService 
startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine 
startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.12
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:32 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase 
createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using 
[SHA1PRNG] took [126] milliseconds.
Jun 26, 2017 10:56:40 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable 
debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned 
but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can 
improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
#### Folder watcher service initialized
```

The last line here is println from ContextLister, and the applic

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: There is no error given

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the listener implementation is blocking at `new FolderWatchService(dir).processEvents();`. You should run event processing in another thread (ie using a ExecutorService to submit `processEvents` job and maybe cancel/shutdown in `contextDestroyed`)